# Was there an alternate ending/episode for General Krell?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, behind-the-scenes

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* I could have sworn the first time I watched the series that the story arc ended with General Krell appreciating the clones' ingenuity and handing them back over to Skywalker after successfully taking the capital.

Was there any sort of alternate ending/episode for General Krell in which he

> wasn't going Sith style?

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are in fact two official versions of the episode *[Carnage of Krell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Carnage_of_Krell)*, the episode

> where he reveals his defection to the Dark Side.

There's the original version and a "Director's Cut" version, which appeared on the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 4 Blu-Ray. However, both end the same way.

As far as I can tell, no alternate ending exists.

You may be conflating the episode with another from the arc, such as *[Darkness on Umbara](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_on_Umbara)*, which does feature Krell grudgingly complimenting the clones.

*Carnage of Krell* does end with the conquering of Umbara's capital, but it's by Obi-Wan's men, not Krell's.